# Existence of ring where not all linear equations have solutions, but all equations of degree $n$ have solutions for some $n \geq 2$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Does there exist a ring $R$, such that not all linear equations $ax+b=0$ have solutions in $R$, but such that there exists an integer $n \geq 2$ such that all $n$-th degree polynomial equations have solutions in $R$? When I say $n$-th degree polynomial equation, I mean the coefficient of the $x^n$ term is nonzero.

Comment: The title is either inartfully phrased, or different from the question in the body. The title should probably say somthing like "but all equations of degree $n$ have solutions for some $n\geq 2$"

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are right. It is a misleading title. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Why is it beneath you to edit and fix your own title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by divisor degree $\,d=1$ in the following

**Lemma** $ $ If all polynomials of degree $n$ have a root in $R$ then so too do those of degree  dividing $\:\!n$

**Proof** $\, $ Write $\,n = dk.\,$ If $\,\deg f = d\,$ then $\,g(x)=f(x^k)\,$ has degree $\,n\,$ so $\,g\,$ has a root $\,r\in R,\,$ so $\,0 = g(r)=f(r^k),\,$ so $\,r^k\in R\,$ is a root of $\,f$.

Answer (score 2):

If $ax+b=0$ has no solutions then $ax^n+b=0$ also can't have any solutions. So no.